# Get other field form selected item rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am making rails app like this.

```
#Gemfile
gem 'cocoon'
gem 'haml-rails'
gem 'simple_form'

rails g scaffold order total_price
rails g scaffold product product_name product_price:integer
rails g model order_detail quantity:integer unit_price:integer subtotal_price:integer order:references product:references


class Order < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :order_details
  has_many :products, through: :order_details

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :order_details, :reject_if => :all_blank, :allow_destroy => true
end

class Product < ApplicationRecord
   has_many :order
end

class order_detail < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :order
  belongs_to :product
end
```

When user make order, use this form,

```
#app/views/order/_form.html.haml
= simple_form_for (@order) do |f|
  #order_details
  = f.simple_fields_for :order_details do |order_detail|
    = render 'order_detail_fields', f: order_detail
  .links.text-right
    = link_to_add_association 'add product', f, :order_details
  = f.input :total_price, disabled: true

  .form-actions
    = f.button :submit

#_order_detail_fields.html.haml
.row.nested-fields
  .col-sm-3
    = f.association :product, :label_method => :name
  .col-sm-1
    = f.input :quantity
  .col-sm-2
    = f.input :unit_price
  .col-sm-2
    = f.input :subtotal_price, disabled: true
  .col-sm-2
    = link_to_remove_association "remove", f
```

So I want to know when user select product, how to put the product_price of product selected into unit_price of order_detail.

I have tried to use ajax or json, but it doesn't work well. If somebody has a good advise or knows good sample, please tell me.

And if it can be calculated quantity * unit_price, when product selected, I can make better.

Comment: change the tags and and jquery on this, you need to add javascript code to make this

Comment: haml is so confusing... Why not erb ? #JustSaying

Comment: @xploshioOn
Thx adivise, I added jquery. I'll write a code later. I'm still making.

Comment: @RafaelBiriba
Exactry sometimes haml confuse me. Esepecially use with js. But it's easier to write code.

Comment: But I can use erb also. If haml added.